# Make marker draggable and clickable

Tags: click, drag, openlayers, marker

I have a vector-layer for displaying markers as features on my map, but now mather, what I do, they are eighter draggable or clickable. What can I do to get both?

```
/*** Init Drag Marker
*/
    var dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(layerTrackMarker, 
        {'onComplete': updateMarker}
    );
    map.addControl(dragFeature);
    dragFeature.activate();

/*** Init Click Marker
*/
    var clickFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layerTrackMarker,
        {}
    );
    map.addControl(clickFeature);
    layerTrackMarker.events.on({
                    "featureselected": function(e) {
                        var markerId = e.feature.geometry.id;
                        removeMarker(markerId);
                        /* ToDo: show context menu */
                    },
                    "featureunselected": function(e) {
                        /* ToDo: hide context menu */
                    }
                });
    clickFeature.activate();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't test it, but wouldn't something like this work?

```
var dragged = false;
var dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(layerTrackMarker, {
    onComplete: function(){
        if(dragged){
            dragCallback();
        }else{
            clickCallback();
        }
    },
    onStart: function(){
        dragged = false;
    },
    onDrag: function(){
        dragged = true;
    }
});
map.addControl(dragFeature);
dragFeature.activate();
```

Edit: onComplete doesn't fire if there was no actual drag. Here's the working code

```
var dragged = false;
var dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(pointLayer, {
    onStart: function(){dragged = false;},
    onDrag: function() {dragged = true;}
});

map.addControl(dragFeature);
dragFeature.activate();

map.events.register("mouseup", map , function(e){
    if(dragged == true){
        alert("dragged");
    }else{
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reKRr/5/

EDIT: this is the less hacky way of doing it

```
var selectFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    pointLayer,
    {
        onSelect: function(){            
            alert("selected");
        }
    }
);

var dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(pointLayer, {
    onComplete: function(){
        alert("drag");
    }
});

dragFeature.handlers['drag'].stopDown = false; 
dragFeature.handlers['drag'].stopUp = false; 
dragFeature.handlers['drag'].stopClick = false; 
dragFeature.handlers['feature'].stopDown = false; 
dragFeature.handlers['feature'].stopUp = false; 
dragFeature.handlers['feature'].stopClick = false; 

map.addControls([selectFeature,dragFeature]);

selectFeature.activate();
dragFeature.activate();
```

Comment: Wow, yeah. You saved my day!

There is only one thing left. Is there a possibility to unselect the marker on mouse up, so it would recognize a secound click on the same marker?

Comment: Thanks, got it.
         onSelect: function(){            
    //My funktion...
    this.unselectAll();
         }